# Is it possible to create text to speech script in php?

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to create text to speech script in php? If yes, can you please tell me how? for example a user enter some text in text box and click on 'play' button. then the script create it audio file on the fly and start playing. any simple stupid method. thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make a PHP script talk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319898/how-do-i-make-a-php-script-talk)

Comment: that is about php+flash, I need it to be in php and/or javascript. thank you

Comment: It's a question about PHP that asks if Flash is required, to which the answer was "no"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Send the text to the server, the server runs PHP code which uses something like the Festival engine to synthesize speech, and the resulting audio is sent back to client-side Javascript (or on a page refresh if you have a non-dynamic client) and played.

PHP, like almost all programming languages, is *Turing complete* and so practically anything that may be done in any other programming language may also be done (potentially with great difficulty, much suffering, and the deaths of unicorns) in PHP.